# how to populate gridview with template fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, gridview

I have a gridview with 30 number of template fields which will be populated by sql. I have to do it by using javascript. I have tried out the following link but that was helpful only for bound fileds but i want to populate all the template fields.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Green/Articles/Populate-ASPNet-GridView-by-binding-DataSet-Client-Side-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

(Note:template fields contain textboxes, labels, checkboxes. and some fields' visble is false)

Please help me with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By learning the link you attached, i can give you a solution. use the following code for template fileds.

```
$("td", row).eq(2).html('<input type="checkbox" id="chk"/>');
```

but note, this would create a runtime control.